# Reading of particular line of text file in WP7 based on some starting string and replacing (overwriting) it

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am able to do read/write/append operation on text file storing in isolated storage in WP7 application.

My scenario is that I am storing space seperated values in text file inside isolated storage.

So if I have to find for some particular line having some starting key then how to overwrite
value for that key without affecting the other line before and after it.

Example:

1. **Key           Value      SomeOtherValue**
2. *status         read       good
3. status1         unread     bad
4. status2         null       cantsay*

So if I have to change the whole second line based on some condition with key as same

**status1    read   good**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store this information in text files then there won't be a way around replacing whole files. The following code does exactly this and might even be what you are doing right now.

```
// replace a given line in a given text file with a given replacement line
private void ReplaceLine(string fileName, int lineNrToBeReplaced, string newLine)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        // the memory writer will hold the read and modified lines
        using (StreamWriter memWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
        {
            // this is for reading lines from the source file
            using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, isf)))
            {
                int lineCount = 0;
                // iterate file and read lines
                while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = fileReader.ReadLine();

                    // check if this is the line which should be replaced; check is done by line 
                    // number but could also be based on content
                    if (lineCount++ != lineNrToBeReplaced)
                    {
                        // just copy line from file
                        memWriter.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // replace line from file
                        memWriter.WriteLine(newLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            memWriter.Flush();
            memWriter.BaseStream.Position = 0;

            // re-create file and save all lines from memory to this file
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
            {
                memWriter.BaseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReplaceLine("test.txt", 1, "status1 read good");
}
```

And I agree with slugster: using SQLCE database might be a solution with better performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could do this, and the method you choose should be best suited to the size and complexity of the data file.

One option to get you started is to use the static [string.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method. This is crude, but if your file is only small then there is nothing wrong with it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("*status read good");
        sb.AppendLine("status1 unread bad");
        sb.AppendLine("status2 null cantsay*");

        string input = sb.ToString();

        var startPos = input.IndexOf("status1");
        var endPos = input.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, startPos);
        var modifiedInput = input.Replace(oneLine.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos), "status1 read good");


        Console.WriteLine(modifiedInput);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already know that that it is possible like this but actually I was thinking of some short and efficient method because my file is having 150 lines and there are many files which i need to rewrite. Also can I write/replace the values if access is ReadWrite and at the moment i found match while traversing the file lines.

Comment: @pan - these are details that should have been part of your question... If the file is 150 lines long then you should get better performance storing it as XML and using XPath queries. If you have a number of these files then maybe you should start thinking about using a database (SQLCE) in isolated storage - this would be way simpler. In any case, I've answered the question as you posed it, maybe you either need to ask a new question or modify your existing question?

Comment: And while I think of it - have you voted in the moderator elections yet? If not, head on over there and do it :) http://stackoverflow.com/election

Comment: thnks for the reply slugster and also for the nice advice. I will surely keep that in mind for future. But my requirement was like that only that I have to write data in txt files only to support other platforms like ios and android becos I am sharing this txt file with other platforms. And I could not find a way whether we can replace a single line on match while reading the txt file. Anyways thnks for all ur help.